# Make bound key functions work even outside of the tkinter frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I've tried to make a basic keylogger using tkinter `bind` system. The code works, but I would like it to work even if the tkinter frame isn't focused. The system works so that when a certain key is pressed, the event knows what key is pressed and adds it to a list. The code works very well.

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")

listeOfKeys = []

def a(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("a")

root.bind('a',  a)


def b(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("b")

root.bind('b',  b)


def c(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("c")

root.bind('c',  c)


def d(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("d")

root.bind('d',  d)


def e(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("e")

root.bind('e',  e)


def f(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("f")

root.bind('f',  f)


def g(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("g")

root.bind('g',  g)


def h(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("h")

root.bind('h',  h)


def i(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("i")

root.bind('i',  i)


def j(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("j")

root.bind('j',  j)


def k(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("k")

root.bind('k',  k)


def l(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("l")

root.bind('l',  l)


def m(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("m")

root.bind('m',  m)


def n(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("n")

root.bind('n',  n)


def o(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("o")

root.bind('o',  o)


def p(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("p")

root.bind('p',  p)


def q(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("q")

root.bind('q',  q)


def r(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("r")

root.bind('r',  r)


def s(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("s")

root.bind('s',  s)


def t(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("t")

root.bind('t',  t)


def u(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("u")

root.bind('u',  u)


def v(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("v")

root.bind('v',  v)


def w(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("w")

root.bind('w',  w)


def x(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("x")

root.bind('x',  x)


def y(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("y")

root.bind('y',  y)


def z(event):
   listeOfKeys.append("z")

root.bind('z',  z)


label = tk.Label(root, text="")
label.pack()

root.mainloop()

print(listeOfKeys)

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about a 'global hook', something which is not possible with tkinter. You could try with something like the `keyboard` module.

https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

Comment: yeah but the point of this piece of code is to be able to make a keylogger with a module you don't need to ```pip install <arandommodule>```

Comment: Ok, reevaluate your life and get rich building something less evil, where you don't have to hide your work.

Answer (score 0):

> The code works, but I would like it to work even if the tkinter frame isn't focused.

You can't. Tkinter doesn't support that. Bindings only work for tkinter widgets, and only for widgets that have the keyboard focus. You'll have to find something specific to the platform you're working on.

Comment: I know. I'm just asking if anyone knows a module which captures keypresses and doesn't require a ```pip install```...

Comment: @gnaboo: Your question doesn't ask for a module recommendation, and asking for library recommendations is off-topic for Stackoverflow.